Winter Bash 2020 Winners!
I want to say a big thank you to everyone who participated in Winter Bash this year. We had a total of 600 users earn 1,070 hats. That's a 3x increase in users since last year.
We had 128k visits to our site this December, the most in any December that I have data for, and it was great to see everyone welcoming new folks to the site and answering questions. Thank you to each of you for keeping the site tidy, active, and welcoming for all of the folks that were interacting with our community for the first time.
Drawing Winners
There's no prize for the most hats this year, but I did want to give a shoutout to @Alex for earning the most hats with 18. Alex has been a prolific contributor for the past two years here and it's great to see their name topping this list.
The following 24 users earned at least 5 hats:
Alex (18 hats)
jncraton (15 hats)
chicks (14 hats)
Michael Verschaeve (13 hats)
zovits (13 hats)
Eran (12 hats)
RSchulz (12 hats)
Christian Rau (9 hats)
A J (9 hats)
JW8 (9 hats)
PeterJ (9 hats)
Phil B. (8 hats)
Zhaph - Ben Duguid (8 hats)
Syberion (8 hats)
Tot Zam (8 hats)
H. Pauwelyn (7 hats)
Alexander O'Mara (7 hats)
Ankit Sharma (7 hats)
mindstormsboi (7 hats)
Akash (6 hats)
Glorfindel (6 hats)
Uli (5 hats)
niamulbengali (5 hats)
Alexander Nied (5 hats)

I've excluded the mods from the drawing as I do each year. The two randomly selected winners are:

Uli
Michael Verschaeve

Congrats to our winners!
Building Competition
Grand Prize
The winner of our building competition this year is the beautiful model of Heinz Field by Christian Rau:

This is a perfectly designed microscale model that captures the architectural detail of this structure perfectly.
Random Winner
The winner selected from the other users submitting content for the contest is the delightful winter hike put together by chicks:

Instructions for winners
All winners will get one set of their choosing worth up to 100 EUR that is in stock or available to order as a backorder at their local shop.lego.com. Winners should email me at my SE username at gmail with shipping information and prize selections. I will be reaching out via other means in the next few days if I don't hear anything from the winners.

I did not expect to be mentioned, since I didn't do anything out of ordinary. But thanks for it! And congratulations to Winter Bash 2020 winners!

Thank you very much! While it raised my own chances, it's a bit unfortunate that so few people participated in the building competition. Given that there was also a random selection, the chances are still a lot higher than just through hats, so it's also surprising more people didn't try their luck. It was already featured in the side bar, maybe a creating dedicated community event could help raise more awareness next year? Anyway, it was really fun and I enjoyed it a lot. I didn't know the set needs to be in stock, though. I think the entire shop is largely bombed out since Black Friday. ;-)

@ChristianRau I would have given you a run for your money, but couldnt participate this year due to personal circumstances. Congrats on your prize!

Wow, thank you so much!  I'm so glad Christian's model won in the building.  This is awesome microscale architecture.  I'm also amazed that I came in second on hats.  It was fun to see which other StackExchanges were near us in the leaderboard.

People named Alex really representing in the hats list! Good work, Alexs!

Thanks a lot ! Also congrats to the other winners.

pity we didn't have many moc submissions...

Received the set yesterday. It's the ship in a bottle. I think it will make for a very lovely vase for the flowers set. Thanks again !
